# How to use TBBMM in Delphi IDE and compiled application

Tags: delphi

I learned that TBBMM seems to have better performance than FastMM.  FastMM is default memory manager in recent release of Delphi IDE.

However, I find not much information regarding the deployment of TBBMM for Delphi users.

How may I replace the default memory manager in Delphi IDE and the compiled application?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to ask in the [autor's forum](http://www.zachsaw.co.cc/forum/viewforum.php?f=13). What you can get from his homepage suggests that it should be not so difficult to use it:

**Installation:**

> Close RAD Studio and
>   backup the existing BorlndMM.dll in
>   your CodeGear RAD Studio Bin folder.
>   Then, unzip the archive into the Bin
>   folder.

**Deploying:**

> you'll have to include ShareMM in your
>   uses list. You'll have to distribute
>   borlndmm.dll and tbbmm.dll along with
>   your executable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of TBBMM.

You'd basically follow the steps as shown in "Sharing Memory" doc page from Embarcadero's help file - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Sharing_Memory (follow the ShareMem instructions, not the SimpleShareMem one). Follow these steps even if you're simply deploying a single EXE without sharing any memory with DLLs.

From the help file:

> List ShareMem as the first unit in the program and library uses clause. Your modules will become dependant on the external BORLNDMM.DLL library, allowing them to share dynamically allocated memory.

Once your app is dependant on the external `BORLNDMM.DLL` library, all you have to do is to deploy the replacement `borlndmm.dll` and `tbbmm.dll` in the same folder as your exe file.